# Redesign of a resultpage card

Tags: usability, layout, cards

I am wondering about a redesign I have been doing. It is about a resultpage in which we have home insurance cards.. the current setup was not flexible enough to show a longer text for the usps.

[image]

My goal for the redesign is to have three clearly separated colomns of the card

First section is for the companys name and rating
The second section is for the USPS and product information
The third is all about pricing information

I am also hoping that the new card is better scanable

[image: Home insurance]

I have also another version in which i have placed the grey tablets below the product name.. this is perhaps easier to scan?

[image: Car]

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I don't have an opinion between the two redesigns, but both are massive improvements to the original.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of where to place the grey tabs, let me ask you this. How big of a priority is that information to the user? Do you want them to learn that information before or after the information in the checklist.

Think of this in terms of conversational UI. If the card and in the information in it would be a person, what would the order of the content be? Either way, the design is great! Good use of contrast, white space and hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Mihnea appreciate it!